# How can I get a shim/polyfill into the global namespace in symfony 5.5?

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces, polyfills, shim

Short version:

How do you get an interface into the global namespace in symfony?

Long version:

I have need for http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php however this particular interface isn't available in PHP 5.3 which we're still running on. We will be moving to a new server offering 5.7 shortly, so I would rather write code that is correct, and just pop a shim in that I can remove when we port over.

I've made a JsonSerializable interface, and if I put it in a regular namespace it loads just fine. However, that means that every Document (using doctrine-mongodb) that I need to serialize will have to be changed when we port. I would much rather put it into the global namespace so that I don't have to mess with my data layer.

I tried putting the file directly into the autoload section of composer.json and not giving it a namespace, but it didn't like that.
"Attempted to load interface "JsonSerializable" from the global namespace in /--path--/Document/AppForm.php line 15. Did you forget a use statement for this interface?"